# SSLContext. Should I reload it?

Tags: java, networking, ssl, keystore, jsse

I am interested in updating a truststore dynamically.
What would be the best option?
Reload `SSLContext` or is it possible to recreate `TrustManagers`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reloading a java.net.http.HttpClient's SSLContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506869/reloading-a-java-net-http-httpclients-sslcontext)

Answer (score 1):

You can't 'reload' an `SSLContext`, but you can certainly create a new one. A custom `TrustManager` won't help, as it is the underlying `TrustManagerFactory` that has the connection to the keystore, not the `TrustManager`.

Comment: It might be possible to write a `TrustManager` that wraps the one obtained from a TMF, with a setter to change the delegated instance. I'm not sure how that would work regarding potential concurrency issues, though.

Comment: So would the best option be to recreate `SSLContext` when it is required?Could I do this:`TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()); tmf.init(ts);`?I found this: http://jcalcote.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/managing-a-dynamic-java-trust-store/ that seems to be what I need but I am not sure if it works or I should keep recreating the `SSLContext` instead

Comment: @EJP:So what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reload the TrustManager within the SSLContext while using the existing SSLContext. See here for the answer which I posted for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69507126/6777695 It contains the full snippet of code samples.